# Merge two Querysets in django that get annotated

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a model "Shift"  for guards schedule program
I do annotation on two django queryset  to create status column for night and day shifts

```
        night_shift=Shift.objects.filter(nightـguard__guards__pk=self.request.user.pk).annotate(status=Value("night", output_field=CharField()))
    day_shift=Shift.objects.filter(dayـguard__guards__pk=self.request.user.pk).annotate(status=Value("day", output_field=CharField()))
```

but when i merge this two queryset with code below

```
my_shift=(day_shift | night_shift).distinct()
```

The annotation field "status" that i create did not work very well and all status get to "day"

what is the solotion ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [Conditional Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-expressions) (The `Case` and `When` expressions)to annotate things conditionally.

```py
from django.db.models import Case, CharField, Q, Value, When


my_shift = Shift.objects.filter(
    Q(nightـguard__guards__pk=self.request.user.pk) | Q(dayـguard__guards__pk=self.request.user.pk)
).annotate(
    status=Case(
        When(
            nightـguard__guards__pk=self.request.user.pk,
            then=Value("night", output_field=CharField())
        ),
        When(
            dayـguard__guards__pk=self.request.user.pk,
            then=Value("day", output_field=CharField())
        ),
    ),
).distinct()
```